# Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-observable

I am attempting to access data from foo.json file using the following `getFoo` function.

```
    getFoo(): Observable<IFoo[]> {
      return this.http.get<IFoo[]>(this.fooUrl).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
      );
   }
```

I return an error:

```
     Argument of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<IFoo[]>, Observable<IFoo[]>>' is 
     not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<IFoo[], IFoo[]>'.
     Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
     Type 'Observable<IFoo[]>' is missing the following properties from type 
    'Observable<IFoo[]>': buffer, bufferCount, bufferTime, bufferToggle, and 104 more.
```

Not exactly sure how to fix this.

Running angular 9.0.3, typescript 3.7.5.

UPDATE:

This is my handleError:

```
private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {

  let errorMessage = '';
  if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
  } else {

    errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
  }
  console.error(errorMessage);
  return _throw (errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: Can you also share the code of your `this.handleError` function please?

Comment: updated the question to include it

Comment: What rxjs version are you using?

Comment: You've imported two different Observables from two different places, which are not compatible. Check your imports and make sure that you use only a single instance of the library.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, the same error is appearing. I am using rxjs 6.5.5 . I also initially had throwError but for some reason the import and the return is not connecting. You are correct that _throw did not work as well.

Comment: @Aidan01 Hmm.. I made an edit to my answer. I am not sure if it will help, but I change the generic parameter  of http.get to `IFoo[] | HttpErrorResponse`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me solve this. The error now is showing     
 "message": "Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpErrorResponse | IFoo[]>'.\n  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HttpErrorResponse | IFoo[]'.\n    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IFoo[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more."

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error. I guess it was fixed by removing "node_modules" folder and "package-lock.json" file. Then "npm install". Build error was fixed for me after this

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct version (without generics on get and with a map function):

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...

getFoo(): Observable<IFoo[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.fooUrl).pipe(
  // tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
  map<any, IFoo[]>(data => {
    console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)); 
    return data;
  }),
  catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately the same error arises.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using one of the latest versions of Angular, it should be using RxJS 6+. `_throw` has been replaced by `throwError`:

```
private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {

  let errorMessage = '';
  if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
  } else {
    errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: 
   ${err.message}`;
  }
  return throwError(errorMessage);
}
```

If the above still does not solve it, you will need to fix `getFoo` such that all paths are actually returning an observable of type `IFoo[]`, since that is declared as the return type of `getFoo`

```
getFoo(): Observable<IFoo[] | HttpErrorResponse> {
  return this.http.get<IFoo[]>(this.fooUrl).pipe(
  map(data => {
    console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    return data;
  }),
  catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```